# User vagrant cannot connect to Windows 2019 ssh server

Tags: ssh, vagrant, packer, sshd, windows-server-2019

I did a `vagrant up` on the vagrant box 
`StefanScherer/windows_2019 (vmware_desktop, 2020.02.12)`
and installed the ssh server via `"Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0"`

The server starts and works fine but the user `vagrant` cannot connect, neither from within the VM (ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1) nor from the outside. It says permission denied. I used `vagrant` as a password, the same that I use to log into the VM.

I created another user `asdf` and I am very well able to connect with this user. So it has something to do with the user `vagrant`. Running `Get-LocalUser` showed no differences between user `vagrant` and my newly created user `asdf`

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-LocalUser

```
Name               Enabled Description
----               ------- -----------
Administrator      True    Built-in account for administering the computer/domain
asdf               True
DefaultAccount     False   A user account managed by the system.
Guest              False   Built-in account for guest access to the computer/domain
sshd               True
vagrant            True    Vagrant User
WDAGUtilityAccount False   A user account managed and used by the system for Windows Defender Application Guard scen...
```

Both accounts are of type  `LocalUser`.
Why is it nor working for `vagrant`? How can I find out what makes this account so special?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is [this bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1252) in openssh for Windows. The hostname (computername) must not be the same as the user name. Both were vagrant in my case.

You can fix it either by modifying your `Vagrantfile` and setting 
`config.vm.hostname` to a value different to `vagrant`. Alternatively, you can change your hostname from inside the VM, e.g. from Powershell via `Rename-Computer -NewName foo -Force -PassThru` (requires restart).